How can I make TailwindCSS @apply rules work?
I am failing to get custom classes to work using @apply. I have followed the docs but it seems tailwind ignores some classes. Is there anything wrong with how I am doing it?
Here is my input file:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .button-primary {
    @apply w-full py-3 px-4 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-[#f23732] text-white hover:bg-[#ff1b15] focus:outline-none focus:bg-[#ff1b15] disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none;
  }
  .sc-checkbox-input {
    @apply shrink-0 mt-0.5 border-gray-200 rounded text-smart-red focus:ring-smart-red;
  }

  .sc-input {
    @apply py-3 px-4 block w-full border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-sm focus:border-smart-red focus:ring-smart-red disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none;
  }
}

My watcher command looks like this in package.json:
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w",

.sc-input never shows up in the output css file, only the first two classes do [.button-primary, .sc-checkbox-input]
Here is my tailwind config as well:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "node_modules/preline/dist/*.js",
    "../templates/**/*.html",
    "../../templates/**/*.html",
    "../../**/templates/**/*.html",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['"Space Grotesk"', "sans-serif"],
        default: ['"Space Grotesk"', "sans-serif"],
      },
      colors: {
        "smart-red": "#F23732",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
    require("@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio"),
    require("preline/plugin"),
  ],
};

I have tried using @layer base {} too but same result.

Consider checking the sc-input can be found as an unbroken string in any file that is covered by the content file globs. This is because, as per the documentation (emphasis mine):

The @layer directive helps you control declaration order by automatically relocating your styles to the corresponding @tailwind directive, and also enables features like modifiers and tree-shaking for your own custom CSS.

Thus, if Tailwind does not see a sc-input string in any of the files that it scans, it will not produce the corresponding CSS rule.
If you need the CSS rule to be produced, you could:

Add the class name to the safelist.
Move the rule outside of any @layer.


As an aside, you may also wish to avoid @apply altogether and rely on your templating engine (if any). As recommended by Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind:

https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1226511611592085504

Confession: The apply feature in Tailwind basically only exists to trick people who are put off by long lists of classes into trying the framework.
You should almost never use it 
Reuse your utility-littered HTML instead.


https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1559250403547652097

I can say with absolute certainty that if I started Tailwind CSS over from scratch, there would be no @​apply 
The behavior is outrageously complicated, everyone struggles to build the right mental model of what it's supposed to do, and it encourages bad CSS architecture.




Moving the class out of any layer worked!
